# Sqoop eval throwing error when I tried to check the connection due to java.io.IOException: Could not load jar into JVM

Tags: hadoop, teradata, amazon-emr, sqoop

I have tried to run the Sqoop eval script through AWS EMR CLI for Teradata connection but  found the error

**Error loading ManagerFactory information from file /usr/lib/sqoop/conf/managers.d/td_connector.txt: java.io.IOException: Could not load jar $SQOOP_HOME/lib/teradata-connector-1.6.5.jar into JVM. (Could not find class org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.)**

Steps I have followed:

1. login to EMR version emr-6.2.0 with the  configuration of hadoop 3 and sqoop 1.4.7 through SSH
2. Downloaded the Teradata Hadoop connector 3.x from teradata downloads
3. moved the teradata hadoop connector to $SQOOP_HOME/lib and installed.
4. created the text file td_connect at /usr/lib/sqoop/conf/managers.d/ and included the text org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager=$SQOOP_HOME/lib/teradata-connector-1.6.5.jar
5. ran the script
   **sqoop eval  --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager  --connect jdbc:teradata://host/database=  --username username --password password  --query 'select top 5 * from table'**

Could you please help to identify the issue

Comment: Don't use the variable `$SQOOP_HOME` in the td_connector.txt file, specify the actual path

Comment: @ Fred, I have used again /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ to refer the td_connector but still it got failed.

Comment: Looks like the "Command Line Edition" of TDCH does not include a connection manager class. The org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager class was included only in the version of the connector provided by Hortonworks (or by Cloudera for HDP). I don't see a TDCH that officially supports EMR 6.x

Comment: Thanks Fred! Let me find any other way around